# Disjoint set and maze creation

Tags: java, disjoint-sets

I am attempting to create a maze using a premade Disjoint set class. I have created a Cell class that contains a boolean variable for each of the four walls. The problem is, how do I create a disjoint set of cell objects? That way I can union the cells and change the boolean variables accordingly.

http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsaajava3/code/DisjSets.java

That is the code for the disjoint set

Comment: May we see this Disjoint set class you're using? Does it use Generics?

Comment: edited question to include the code

Comment: Are you allowed to change the class at all? If not, then you'll need to Union the different rooms (identified as integers) and design your own logic for how a player navigates through the cells. This isn't trivial and if you want to use that DisjSets class you're going to have to put a fair bit of planning into the logic of it

Answer (score 0):

A disjoint set data-structure is not suited for this particular problem.

Attempting to force your solution to use it is just going to give you poor code and a bad design.

Not to mention that there is a much simpler, more elegant solution.

In order to generate a perfect (one unique path between any two points) maze:

1. create an array of N by M cells, keeping track of each wall in each cell
2. choose a cell at random
3. from your current cell (A), select a non-visited neighbour (B), if there are no such neighbours, go back to your previously visited cell and start from step (3)
4. break down the wall between A and B
5. mark B as the current cell (or push it in a list or similar datastructure)
6. if all cells have been visited, end. else go back to step (3)

All you need is a grid, and a list.